# jQuery I want to add an active class to the linked ID of an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I've written an alphabet navigation program- I have anchor linked linked to h4 tags. When I click the a-tag, I want the element with the matching ID to have a class of active. When you click another anchor tag, it removes the class of active and assigns it to another element. Here's what I have so far:

```
<ul class="no-bullet inline">
            <li><a class="scroller" href="#a"><strong>A</strong></a></li>
            <li><a class="scroller" href="#b"><strong>B</strong></a></li>
            <li><a class="scroller" href="#c"><strong>C</strong></a></li>

          </ul>

<h4 class="alpha-heading" id="a"><strong>A</strong></h4>

<h4 class="alpha-heading" id="b"><strong>B</strong></h4>

<h4 class="alpha-heading" id="c"><strong>C</strong></h4>


$("scroller").on("click", function(){
function matchAlpha(){
var matchID = $(this).attr("href");
find.$(matchID).find.$(alpha-heading).removeClass("active");
find.$(matchID).find.$(this).$(alpha-heading).addClass("active");
}

});
```

Comment: You've got a named function in your anonymous event handler function, but you never call it. If that named function did run, you would get several runtime errors. You may wish to run through some jQuery tutorials (and possibly some basic JavaScript ones) to get a handle on the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce your code to a single line in a click handler:

```js
$('.scroller').click(function() {
  $($(this).attr('href')).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
})
```

```css
.active {
  background: #faa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="no-bullet inline">
  <li><a class="scroller" href="#a"><strong>A</strong></a></li>
  <li><a class="scroller" href="#b"><strong>B</strong></a></li>
  <li><a class="scroller" href="#c"><strong>C</strong></a></li>

</ul>

<h4 class="alpha-heading" id="a"><strong>A</strong></h4>

<h4 class="alpha-heading" id="b"><strong>B</strong></h4>

<h4 class="alpha-heading" id="c"><strong>C</strong></h4>
```

The way this works is as follows:

- `$('.scroller').click(function() {`: When clicking on a link with the scroller class
- `$(this).attr('href')` Get the href attribute
- Select it and add the active class to it with `.addClass('active')`
- The select all the siblings of that element and remove the active class with `.siblings().removeClass('active')`

Answer (score 1):

Few things needs to fix in your code.

1. add `.` to scoller to look for class.
2. use `.alpha-heading` to remove active from previous active.You can even do `.alpha-heading.active` to be more specific
3. use `matchID` as id selector

```js
$(".scroller").on("click", function() {
  var matchID = $(this).attr("href");
  //$('.alpha-heading').removeClass("active");
  $('.alpha-heading.active').removeClass("active");
  $(matchID).addClass("active");


});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="no-bullet inline">
  <li><a class="scroller" href="#a"><strong>A</strong></a></li>
  <li><a class="scroller" href="#b"><strong>B</strong></a></li>
  <li><a class="scroller" href="#c"><strong>C</strong></a></li>

</ul>

<h4 class="alpha-heading" id="a"><strong>A</strong></h4>

<h4 class="alpha-heading" id="b"><strong>B</strong></h4>

<h4 class="alpha-heading" id="c"><strong>C</strong></h4>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to add missing `.` in the `scroller` and then use the `href` as selector to add active class for the clicked element. Below is the updated working version of your code:

```js
$(".scroller").on("click", function() {
  $('h4.alpha-heading').removeClass('active');
  $($(this).attr('href')).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="no-bullet inline">
  <li><a class="scroller" href="#a"><strong>A</strong></a></li>
  <li><a class="scroller" href="#b"><strong>B</strong></a></li>
  <li><a class="scroller" href="#c"><strong>C</strong></a></li>

</ul>

<h4 class="alpha-heading" id="a"><strong>A</strong></h4>

<h4 class="alpha-heading" id="b"><strong>B</strong></h4>

<h4 class="alpha-heading" id="c"><strong>C</strong></h4>
```